# Boolean value in firestore toggled with check box. Requires 2 clicks to alter value?

Tags: android, firebase, checkbox, boolean

I've created an `adapter` with an `OnItemClickListener` and set it to a `checkbox`. I've succeeded in making the `checkbox` toggle a `Boolean` value in `Firebase` firestore but it takes 2 clicks to change the value.

When clicking the `checkbox` it doesn't toggle to checked until the second click. The same goes for unchecking.

The method is called in `onCreate`.

"done" is the Boolean field in my database.

The `checkbox` is on a `recyclerview` nested in another `recyclerview`. This is why it has a nested collection/document and a variable for an ID. I excluded the intents used to create the variables.

```
private void setUpCheckBox() {

    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ToDoAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, final int 
        position) {

        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_complete);


            Map<String, Object> done = new HashMap<>();

            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                done.put("done", true);
            }
            if (!checkBox.isChecked()) {
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
                done.put("done", false);
            }

            db.collection("customer2").document(id1).collection("To Do").document(id2)
                    .set(done, SetOptions.merge())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomerProfile.this, id2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    });
        }
    });
}
```

This is a nested Class in my adapter Class.

```
private OnItemClickListener listener;
```

listener is declared in parent class.

```
    class ToDoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CheckBox checkBoxComplete;

        public ToDoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            checkBoxComplete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_complete);

            checkBoxComplete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;

    }
}
```